Select2 plugin is not working on html which created after page load
I am appending html (select dropdown) on click. But select2 only works if it gets any select dropdown on page load.
If select dropdown created after page load on click with jquery then select2 won't work in such case for created select tag.
How select2 can work on newly generated html?
This happens not only for select2 but for every jquery function. Any solution?

"How select2 can work on newly generated html?" - same as it worked on the static HTML? Select the newly inserted elements, and then initialize select2 on them.

@CBroe It's not working. When new html (select tag) added on page on click, then it already has "select2" class in it. But search in dropdown doesn't show up. It only shows up when select tag loads on page load with other html.

"When new html (select tag) added on page on click, then it already has "select2" class in it." - but that does not mean that the select2 script will retro-actively look for any such new elements - it only works on the elements that were already in the document at the time you initialized it. So, as I already said, you need to initialize it again, for those newly added fields.

"And I don't know why down vote since its pretty tricky issue." - has less to do with the "trickiness" of the issue, and more with how you are posting. If you have not read [ask] and [mre] yet, then I would suggest you do so now.

@CBroe Okay, adding initial script again in click function did the trick. Now i have 2 intialization, one at page load and other on click function. Thanks. You can post it as answer.

You can do is like this
<select onchange="MyFunc()" ></select>

<script>function myFunc() { YOUR CODE HERE }</script>

